# Font Size Issues with Galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I am using the code as below to show an popup in my application.

```
final String[] items = {"Vishal", "Android", "Issue"};

        Button btnClick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                builderAppointmentNew = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builderAppointmentNew.setTitle("Dialogs");
                builderAppointmentNew.setItems(items,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            }
                        });
                builderAppointmentNew.show();
            }
        });
```

Now the issue is when I am running the same on Galaxy S3(4.65in 720p/SDK) The dialog is not showing properly until I touch it.

[image: Before touching the Screen][image: After Touching the Screen]

when I touch the dialog it renders properly as in 2nd screenshot.

My Manifest contains..

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
```

Its working fine with other devices I have.

**UPDATE :**

If I'll change **android:minSdkVersion="3"** to **android:minSdkVersion="8"**, then its working properly but I can't do it as per app requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Set your application target to *at least* SDK version 11 and leave the minimum SDK version at 3, if that's the lowest you can get.

It should be like this in your case:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

Comment: What is the reason for doing so? is it mentioned somewhere in the docs? or just a guess?

Comment: If it works by changing his minimum SDK version, then this should work as well. I assume a target SDK is required.